# selecting items in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i want to select booktitle with status paid

but if there no booktitle with status paid display other booktitle with other status

```
ITEMS

ID  bookname  code
1   cats      222
2   dogs      555
3   cows      777
4   goat      888
5   rubbit    999


PRODUCTS

ID booktitle  status 
1  222        paid
2  555        paid
3  777        notpyed
4  888        waitpyed
5  999        notmoney
```

Query

```
 SELECT 
      snd.code,  m.booktitle FROM
      products as m
      JOIN items as snd ON snd.code = m.booktitle WHERE CASE WHEN (m.status = 'paid') > 0 THEN m.status = 'paid' ELSE m.status = 'notpyed'  OR m.status = 'waitpyed'
      OR m.status = 'notmoney' END
```

Comment: You're joining on the wrong columns: `JOIN items as snd ON snd.bookname = m.booktitle`. You're trying to match bookname and booktitle, which hold different data. I believe you meant `snd.code` instead of `snd.bookname`.

Comment: yes its snd.code, question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a subquery to get the sum of books paid

The else part could be `m.status <> 'paid'` , but i don't know how many sti you have

> ```
>  SELECT 
>       snd.code,  m.booktitle FROM
>       PRODUCTS as m
>       JOIN ITEMS as snd ON snd.code = m.booktitle 
>       WHERE CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(status = 'paid') FROM  PRODUCTS) > 0 THEN m.status = 'paid' 
>                              ELSE m.status = 'notpyed'  OR m.status = 'waitpyed'
>                                   OR m.status = 'notmoney' END
> ```
>
> ```
> code | booktitle
> ---: | --------:
>  222 |       222
>  555 |       555
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25411b590d3e1cf43403be0d281b8196)*